# Link between phenylalanine and Hyperaldosteronism?

Tags: nutrition, endocrinology

I've obviously googled, but I was curious if anyone with actual medical knowledge has seen any studies linking elevated dietary sources of phenylalanine and Hyperaldosteronism.